# Windows Phone 8 Control has undefined or erratic behaviour on the first click/interaction

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

There are some controls on windows phone that behave different on the first interaction with them than on subsequent ones. e.g. a button control takes about 3-5 seconds to initialize the required action the first time the button is pressed, however on subsequent clicks it works immediately.

Another usercontrol that adjusts its height based on the key press doesn't adjust properly the first time, however the second time it works.

Is there a way to either prepare the controls, i.e. set them in a ready state so that all the clicks behave the same, or can first click can be faked to bypass this annoying behaviour?

Also what is causing this problem?

NB:- I am testing on a Lumia 520 device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out from this app performance document why it was happening , [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff967560(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_Applicationstartup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff967560%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_Applicationstartup).

I have a loading panel that is set to collapsed by default and only set visible once the button is clicked. According to the document, elements in collapsed state arent added to memory, so this means the first time it needs to initialize the panel and it doesnt need to in subsequent tries.

The other UI control behaving weirdly was also due to its parent's height not being adjusted after its own height is adjusted the first time, so adjusting the parent height as well fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately There is no way to prepare the controls. [Nokia Lumia 520](http://www.nokia.com/in-en/phones/phone/lumia-520/specifications/) comes in Lower Memory Device So Its behaviour seems slow at loading first time in memory and there are so many Background tasks also runnig at a same point of time. You should try it in Higher Memory Device and see the Behaviour.